# How to run a user defined function using a for loop that prints a sequence of numbers?

Tags: r

I want to create a simple function that prints the different sequences of numbers for 1 to N given the different choices of N. Below code works for only the 1st value of N that is 10 and not for the 2nd value of N (20). In fact, its showing an warning

> In 1:N : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used.

```
try<-function(N=NULL)
     {
       for(val in N)
        {
          x<-1:N 
          print(x)
        } 

 }

y<-try(N=c(10,20))
```

Comment: `lapply( c(10,20), function(x) { 1:x } )` ?

Comment: Avoid using existed function names, so change `try` to `try_sqn` for example. Change `N` to `seq(N)` and `1:N` to `1:N[val]` and it will work.

Comment: This one works. Thanks Wimpel.